# D3 Multicolumn Relative Stack Chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I am currently modifying the following example to produce a multi horizontal relative stack chart. The following example is a "single" stack chart example.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDkWP/

Here is my version however I get NaN X and Width values and I'm looking to find out why. Thank you.

Within the SVG the structure is as follows for each of the : -

g[ g [rect, rect, rect]], g[ g [rect, rect, rect]]

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/scottietom/7c3vb4e9/

```
        var dataset = [
                       [
                        [{x: 0,y: 100}],[{x: 0,y: 30}],[{x: 0,y: 50}]], 
                        [[{x: 0,y: 100}],[{x: 0,y: 30}],[{x: 0,y: 50}]]
                      ];

        //Set up stack method
        var stack = d3.layout.stack();

        //Data, stacked
        for (i=0; i<dataset.length; i++) {
          stack(dataset[i]);
        }

        //Set up scales
        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                return d3.max(d, function (d) {
                return d.y0 + d.y;
            });
        })])
        .range([0, w]);

        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
        var colors = d3.scale.category10();
        //or make your own colour palet
        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#1459D9", "#148DD9", "#87ceeb", "#daa520"]);

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select(".pathanalysis_diagram")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Add a group for each row of data
        var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color(i);
        });

        // Add a rect for each data value
        var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return xScale(d.y0);
            })
            .attr("y", 50)
            .attr("height", 50)
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return xScale(d.y);
            });
```

Comment: In the fiddle three rectangles are stacked. So what is the question ?

Comment: I am wanting to transform this code to accept multiple rows and the code beneath the link is my attempt.

Comment: I believe that something is wrong with the way I stack my data which is then referred to within the linear scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle with your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/z73u6mro/

I called the nested dataset arrayOfDatasets so the changes become more clear.
First you have to call stack() for each of the datasets:

```
arrayOfDatasets.forEach(function (dataset) {stack(dataset); });
```

Then you have to retrieve the max for xScale:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(arrayOfDatasets, function (dataset) {      
      return d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
        return d3.max(d, function (d) {
            return d.y0 + d.y;
        });
      })
    })])
    .range([0, w]);
```

Finally, you just have to access the data properly and translate the datasets so they don't overlap:

```
var groupOfGroups = svg.selectAll("g.toplevel")
    .data(arrayOfDatasets)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "toplevel")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i ) {return "translate(0, " + (-i * 55) + ")"; });   

// Add a group for each row of data
var groups = groupOfGroups.selectAll("g.dataset")
    .data(function(d) {return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "dataset")
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
});
```

You might still store your datasets differently since it's not clear why you have the x values in them.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I notice however that if the two datasets don't equal 100 in value then one is longer than the other. Is there a simple way to make each line independent in this matter so that each line is always 100% in width regardless of value?

Comment: I thought that is worked as designed and how it should be... that's why you want to have one xScale ? If you are asking for relative stack charts, the elements in the each dataset should sum up to 100 anyway. If you want to all of them having the same width I suggest you implement a separate xScale for each dataset.

Comment: If you mean the datasets come in absolut, but just the visualization is relative, and the one xScale is the  % scale, then all you have to do is to convert your data to % in the beginning and everything else just works as now.